# Printing medium sized image

Tags: functions, images, post-thumbnails

I am having some issue with printing the actual resized version of the `medium` image within my WordPress website.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "medium" ); print $thumbnail[0]; ?>" class="new-artwork"></a>
```

Above is my current featured image portion, how ever I want it to return the url which looks like this

```
 http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/our-file-name-300x300.jpg
```

but instead it's returning this

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/our-file-name.jpg
```

Even when going to the url manually it does not displayed a resized version of my existing image, I thought that the medium, full, thumbnail versions was default within WordPress.

Comment: Does the size _actually exist_, as in there is such file in file system? Something might have interfered with generating it back when image was uploaded.

Comment: Medium is a default option, but plugins and themes can change things. Use FTP to check whether your file actually exists in a medium size, and also remember that depending on cropping you may have 300x200, 300x100, etc. image sizes. You may want to check Settings > Media for options, check plugins and themes, adjust as needed, and then run a thumbnail regeneration plugin to create the missing medium images once you track down the cause of them being missing.